# Facebook Authorization using LWUIT Browser

Tags: java-me, facebook, lwuit

I am facing problem with LWUIT browser in conjunction with Facebook OAuth API.

I am trying to authorize our application to use Facebook services on a mobile client using LWUIT browser, which is available on SVN. I can go as far as the permissions page where you see a list of permissions followed by the "Allow" and "deny" buttons. The moment I click on the "Allow" button, I am again being redirected to Facebook login page (m.facebook.com) instead of forwarding to our application webpage. Has anyone encountered this problem and has managed to get around it?

From my understanding, I believe there is a problem in parsing the page and hence there is a failure in generating an access code which in turn is responsible for forwarding back to the application webpage.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could shed some light on the predicament.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a simulator with the proper certificate chain from Facebook. Try Java SDK 3.0.5 or newer (the very latest ME SDK). This is an SSL problem in a few J2ME mobile stacks.

Comment: Thanks for the response Shai. I am not trying on the emulator, but on the actual devices. Even the newest devices like the Nokia X3-02 (S40 6th edition) seems to have this problem.

Comment: If I remember correctly we resolved issue by modifying LWUIT sources because LWUIT browser doesn't accept several cookies headers

Comment: Since LWUIT does log to facebook this works for us in the current release with the current cookie code. Did you try the facebook demo Chen published a while back?

Comment: I have recently tried on the new J2ME SDK 3.0.5 and it does work on the emulator, but the issue does hold true on the target device, Nokia X3-02 and certain other S60 devices.